# Ordered partition in a summation

Tags: summation, partitions

I need to ensure that the order is important and that $a_1a_2a_2$ is different from $a_2a_1a_2$ or as a matter of fact, any other possibility. In other words, $a_m$s are considered non-commutative. So how do I write this up in Mathematica, as I already figured out that `IntegerPartitions` is not something I'm looking for? The deal is with Ordered Partitions. $$\sum_{i_1+i_2+...+i_m=n}a_{i_1}a_{i_2}...a_{i_m}\Big\}$$ Thankful for your efforts.

## Update

For more context, this question is part of another one:

[Double summation involving partition of a number n as a condition](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/230746/43522)

Comment: Have you checked the non-commutative multiply `**`? See [`NonCommutativeMultiply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
n = 4
times[x_] := x;
times[args__] := NonCommutativeMultiply[args];
Total[
 times @@@ Map[Subscript[a, #] &,
   Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[n], 1],
   {2}
  ]
]
```

> [image]

Comment: Well that's what I require, but I would like you to address the question in the website: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230746/double-summation-involving-partition-of-a-number-n-as-a-condition/230771#230771
Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: @user74846 If this question is related to the other one, you should include a link to it in the question.

Comment: @user74846, this is quite different from the other question, so asking a separate question is fine. Otherwise, you should not have neglected to put in *all* requirements in your other question to begin with.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Yes @J.M. I think I should have elaborated the question well enough. I will ensure this next time. But to be clear, at the start I was looking for ordered partition only, though I admit I didn't frame up well.